# C - Basic For Loop

Tags: c

I seem to be having some issues with this 'for' loop, it is an exam question and I cannot figure out why my logic is incorrect.

```
int n = 1, r, i;

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    n *= 2;

r = n--;
```

Find the value of r and n after this code has been run.

Here is my logic for this(on paper, hence the image link):
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUXti.jpg)

The correct output is however, n=31 and r=32. Why is this? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why should it be `32`?

Comment: Because after the loop n is 32 and the VALUE of n is being changed when you do n--. However before n-- is being executed n is stored in r which is 32, then post decrement n--.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line `r = n--;` decrements n after it is assigned to r.

Answer (score 8):

This is not the `for` issue, but `--n` and `n--`.

- `n--` first return `n` as the value of the expression `n--`, then do the subtraction `n <- n-1`.
- `--n` first do the subtraction `n <- n-1`, and then return the new value of `n` as the value of `--n`

---

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Comment: Ah. I see. So when it is something like say y = x--. The value of y will be the value of x before the decrement. Apart from ++ and --, are there any other scenarios in which this may occur?

Comment: @FShiwani not exactly, `=` is at lowest priority, `n--` happens before assign. In a language, there are 2 types, `expression` and `statement`, every `expression` has a value, such as `n--`, so `r=n--` means assign `r` to the value of **expression** `n--`, and the value of `n--` is value of `n` before decrement.

Answer (score -2):

```html
int n = 1, r = 0, i;

  for(i=0; i<=5; i++)
    r *= 2;

n = r--;
```

Here's the final answer. Go check it. Hope it helps.

Comment: It is not _wrong_ to initialize `r` to 0, but also not necessary, since `r` is assigned the value of `n` before the final postdecrement. It is wrong to remove the declaration for `i`. But, why do you want to change the controlling expression of the `for` statement? The question was about why this code yields final values for `r` and `n` of 32 and 31, respectively.